# How to copy and paste in Log File Viewer

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the attached screen displaying.

I would like to copy the text message column into my paste buffer so I can paste it into an editor and format it.

When I right click on the message column no context menu appears.

[image: Log File Viewer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the file in a text editor.

Default location is `Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG and ERRORLOG.n`.

If it is not in the default location, you can locate the file with this command:

```
USE master
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Logging SQL Server messages in file', NULL, NULL, N'asc' 
GO
```

Comment: I have not actually checked this is right yet, but it makes sense and I want to give him his credit.

Answer (score 2):

Use the export button (seen in your screenshot) to save the log file as a text file to anywhere you want.

You don't actually have to go hunting it down as suggested in the currently accepted answer.